# How can I disable the GPS functionality from my android phone at the kernel level?

Tags: updates, linux, kernel, android-versions

How can I disable the GPS functionality from my android phone at the kernel level? I know this requires (though not sure) disabling either device drivers for GPS or kernel module BUT how to do it exactly?

By kernel level, I mean that GPS is no longer there like in soft form, its hardware still exists but it is of no use. If I disable it application level, it still tracks me , apps might access it. What I want is that there is no communication between the hardware and software. So the apps perceive that this phone doesnt have a GPS. I hope you get my point. I have been able to do this with bluetooth i.e.I removed bluetooth permissions from xml files listed in the system/etc/permissions folder of its stock rom, bluetooth is no longer there but the same doesn't work for GPS.

Comment: Kernel modifications are device specific. What device do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still have the original ROM installed on your mobile, this will not be possible, because on the original kernels there are no options in-build in the kernel to toggle the components at that level.

In case your phone is rooted, you can always use a custom kernel that would have this kind of option, which in my opinion is very rare because itsn't an option generally sought.

Also, assuming you can include a feature like this manually (in sources), you will have to re-compile the kernel, which is not necessarily easy for someone inexperienced in this field.